# How can I increase the maximum branch width in ggtree?

Tags: r, phylogeny, ggtree

I added some traits to the branches of my phylogram and scaled the branch widths to their value:

```
library(ggtree)
library(tidyverse)

tree <- rtree(3, rooted = T)
trait <- data.frame(node = 1:(length(tree$edge.length)+1),
                    thing = rnorm(n = length(tree$edge.length)+1, mean = 4))

t <- full_join(tree, trait)
ggtree(t, aes(size = thing))
```

Especially if the trait values have a large range, the branch width needs to be able to reflect that. How can I specify the maximum width of the branches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the `trait$thing` vector directly when mapping the `size` aesthetic. Best to make sure `trait` is ordered by `tree$tip.label`, although `ggtree` might be doing some matching internally.

```
library(ggtree)

tree <- rtree(3, rooted = T)
trait <- data.frame(node = 1:(length(tree$edge.length)+1),
                    thing = rnorm(n = length(tree$edge.length)+1, mean = 4))

ggtree(tr = tree, aes(size = trait$thing)) + 
  scale_size_continuous(range = c(0.2, 2))
```

From `?scale_size_continuous`:

> range
>
> a numeric vector of length 2 that specifies the minimum and maximum size of the plotting symbol after transformation.

Comment: This gives me exactly the same result.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that point in the question. See my edit. You should be able to treat the edge width as any other aesthetic and control the size of symbols through `scale_size_continuous`.

Comment: Thank you, that works! Somehow I had not thought of just using `scale_size_continuous`.